# Salesforce SSO: SAML Response signature key's identifier in KeyInfo element

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, xml-signature

When verifying SAML2 signature through the SAML verification tool, if the KeyInfo in the X509Data is X509Certificate, verification is successful.

```
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509Certificate>MIIEVTCCA.....</X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
```

If the KeyInfo is other type (X509SubjectName / X509SKI / X509IssuerSerial etc.) then verification fails.

```
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509SKI>E5oVIj....</X509SKI>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
```

Validation result: *Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? false*

[Salesforce SAML assertion validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjiks.png)

The problem is that we cannot use X509Certificate element due to 3rd party limitations.

Does Salesforce allow using any key identifiers in SAML responses instead of X509Certificate element?